# using strsplit to split a variable three ways

Tags: r, strsplit

I have a variable that I would like to split... Each line is different but it either has 2 string expression separated by a ","; 3 string expression separate by a ','; 1 string expression; or nothing at all

For Example:

```
     indel
row1 +1C
row2 +1C,+2CC
row3 0
row4 +1C,+2CC,-1C
```

Essentially what I want to do is make 3 different variables for each of the possible three string expression.  Of course, some rows will have 2, or 1 or none.

I have been able to split and created two different variables for the first two string expression using:

```
mito$indel1 <- sapply(strsplit(as.character(mito$indel),","),function(x) x[1])
mito$indel2 <- sapply(strsplit(as.character(mito$indel),","),function(x) x[2])
```

But of course, there is third string expression.  I was thinking of creating a temporary indel2 variable, then splitting this again to make the third, but the problem with using the  R script above is that it creates the variables as:

```
     indel         Indel1    Indel2
row1 +1C           +1C       NA
row2 +1C,+2CC      +1C       +2CC
row3 0             0         NA
row4 +1C,+2T,-1C   +1C       +2T
```

I'm sure this has to do with the second "," in the string and R is getting confused.  But is there a way to overcome this without having to edit the entire variable for each row.

I've also tried the following with no luck:

```
mito$indel2 <- sapply(strsplit(sapply(strsplit(as.character(mito$indel),","),function(x) x[2]),","),function(x) x[1])
mito$indel3 <- sapply(strsplit(sapply(strsplit(as.character(mito$indel),","),function(x) x[2]),","),function(x) x[2])
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Does `mito$indel3 <- sapply(strsplit(as.character(mito$indel),","),function(x) x[3])` not accomplish what you want?

Comment: Usually that would work, but somehow it doesn't work for this case.  Probably me doing something wrong somewhere but I'll have another go at it..

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could also use `read.table` for this.

```
read.table(text=as.character(dat$V1), sep=',', fill=TRUE, as.is=TRUE)
#    V1   V2  V3
# 1 +1C         
# 2 +1C +2CC    
# 3   0         
# 4 +1C +2CC -1C
```

Comment: @BrandonBertelsen Same, I've seen this numerous times and it never comes to mind when I need it.

Comment: @TylerRinker, and yet, if you look at the code for `read.concat`, it's mostly this :-)  The main difference is that `read.concat` relies on `count.fields` since my experience has been that a lot of data in this format does not necessarily have the correct number of fields in the first handful of lines of data.

Answer (score 5):

Maybe the `splitstackshape` package:

```
library(splitstackshape)
dat <- read.table(text="+1C
+1C,+2CC
0
+1C,+2CC,-1C", header=FALSE)

splitstackshape:::read.concat(dat[, 1], "var", ",")

##  var_1 var_2 var_3
## 1   +1C            
## 2   +1C  +2CC      
## 3     0            
## 4   +1C  +2CC   -1C
```

A second base way but @Matthew's is a much better approach:

```
dat2 <- strsplit(as.character(dat[, 1]), ",")
lens <- sapply(dat2, length)
max(lens)
do.call(rbind, lapply(dat2, function(x) {
    x[max(lens)  + 1] <- NA
    x
}))[, -c(max(lens) + 1)]

##      [,1]  [,2]   [,3] 
## [1,] "+1C" NA     NA   
## [2,] "+1C" "+2CC" NA   
## [3,] "0"   NA     NA   
## [4,] "+1C" "+2CC" "-1C"
```

Comment: but it's rarely a good idea to make your code dependent on a non-exported function.

Comment: @flodel I'd disagree.  I'd say for packages yes but for writing code for analysis, meh.  However, I'd like Ananda Mahto to weigh in here as to why `read.concat` isn't exported but shown a bunch in the documentation.

Comment: `concat.split(data = dat, split.col = "V1", drop = TRUE)`

Comment: @flodel and Tyler, Henrik's use is more what I had in mind (it's a helper function for two versions of the `concat.split` functions), which is why I hadn't exported it. Since I find it helpful as it is, I also created a documentation page for it.